# Dropdown list is not displayed on mobile-devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm experiencing a problem with an autocomplete dropdown list not working on iPhones in my WordPress-plugin. The page itself is elementor based.

The dropdown list is not being displayed on mobile devices, although I can see the different  showing up in the console. I have implemented a js-function, which fetches data from a .json-file to populate the dropdown list based on user input. I have verified that the issue is not related to CSS or Elementor. Could it be due to the createElement function not being used correctly? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the form: [www.cleverlaw.de/elementor-1470](http://www.cleverlaw.de/elementor-1470)

The second and the last field are affected.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to switch the user agent on my computer to iPhone/Safari and it worked. However, if I switch the user agent in safari on my iPhone to macOS/Chrome, it doesn't work.

This is the form:

```
 <form method="post" id="flight_form" action="">
            <label for="flight_number">Flight Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="flight_number" name="flight_number">
    
            <label for="departure_airport">Departure Airport:</label>
            <input type="text" id="departure_airport" name="departure_airport" autocomplete="off" required>
            <div id="departure_airport_dropdown" style="display: none;"></div>
    
            <label for="destination_airport">Destination Airport:</label>
            <input type="text" id="destination_airport" name="destination_airport" autocomplete="off" required>
            <div id="destination_airport_dropdown" style="display: none;"></div>
    
           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="send-button" value="Send" onclick="calculateDistance(); return false;">
        </form>
```

This is the js-function:

```
function showMatchingAirports(searchTerm, targetDropdown) {
  if (searchTerm.length < 2) {
    targetDropdown.innerHTML = '';
    targetDropdown.style.display = 'none';
    return;
  }

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var airports = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var dropdown = document.createElement('div'); 
      
      for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option'); 
        option.value = airports[i].iata_code;
        option.textContent = airports[i].name;
        dropdown.appendChild(option); 
      }
      
      targetDropdown.innerHTML = ''; 
      targetDropdown.appendChild(dropdown); 
      targetDropdown.style.display = 'block'; 
      var dropdownOptions = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('option');
      for (var j = 0; j < dropdownOptions.length; j++) {
        dropdownOptions[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
          var selectedValue = this.value;
          var inputField = targetDropdown.previousElementSibling;
          inputField.value = selectedValue;
          targetDropdown.style.display = 'none';
        });
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', '<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>get_matching_airports.php?search_term=' + searchTerm, true);
  xhttp.send();
}


document.getElementById('departure_airport').addEventListener('input', function() {
    var searchTerm = this.value.trim();
    var targetDropdown = document.getElementById('departure_airport_dropdown');
    showMatchingAirports(searchTerm, targetDropdown);
});

document.getElementById('destination_airport').addEventListener('input', function() {
    var searchTerm = this.value.trim();
    var targetDropdown = document.getElementById('destination_airport_dropdown');
    showMatchingAirports(searchTerm, targetDropdown);
});
```

This is get-matching-airports.php:

```
<?php
$json_file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/airports.json';
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_file_path);
$airports = json_decode($json_data, true);

$search_term = isset($_GET['search_term']) ? $_GET['search_term'] : '';

$matching_airports = array();

foreach ($airports as $airport) {
    if (stripos($airport['name'], $search_term) === 0) {
        $matching_airports[] = $airport;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($matching_airports);
exit;
?>
```

I tried different user agents and browsers and also checked the CSS.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to PHP? Usually, PHP does not care (and even not know) whether a mobile device or any other starts the request. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I know...It works on my computer even when I'm switching the user agent to iPhone / safari, but not on my iPhone (no matter which user agent I'm using). I tried to change the "departure-airport-dropdown" - <div> to a <select> but it didn't work out either. The JS and PHP is working properly, bc I can see the results showing up in my console, but it doesn't get displayed.

Comment: _"I tried to change the "departure-airport-dropdown" - <div> to a <select> but it didn't work out either."_ - a) you appear to be referring to an element that is not even contained in the code you have shown us above? Even if it might be somewhere on the live page you referred us to - what you are talking about in regard to the problem, should be contained directly in the question here. So if that is relevant, then please update the above code so that everyone can see what you are talking about.

Comment: And b) - what _sense_ would that even make? You can not just switch div for select, and then expect the same kind of functionality.

Comment: _"bc I can see the results showing up in my console"_ - results of what, exactly? There is no `console` related statement anywhere in the code you have shown us, so again, not sure what you are even talking about here. And _if_ you made any debug outputs in that code, then if would also be of interest to know _where_ exactly.

Comment: And probably not relevant at this point, but: `dropdownOptions[j].addEventListener('click'` - click handlers on options are a rather bad idea, that has some issues with browser support. (Might be only legacy browsers at this point, but still.) Using a `change` handler on the select element itself, is preferable.

Comment: @CBroe the departure_airport_dropdown <div> is contained in the code above. The function **showMatchingAirports** fetches data from a .json file based on the user input and creates <options> which are being diplayed inside the departure_airport_dropdown <div> as a dropdown.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. But then this would mean that you are really just appending options to a div element? That is a rather bad idea to begin with, IMHO - and perhaps it is also somehow the reason it doesn't work on mobile? You said you tried to replace that div with a select - but you are still creating an additional div container first, that you are appending your options to, so your structure would still be select -> div -> options, which is also not valid HTML. So try and use a select field, but populate it with the options _directly_, without adding any additional wrapper elements.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your "select" element: You just created a div containing an option - which will not work on mobile devices:

```html
<!-- Your solution -->
<div id="departure_airport_dropdown" style="display: block;">
  <div>
    <option value="STR">Stuttgart</option>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Correct solution -->
<select id="departure_airport_dropdown" style="display: block;">
  <option value="STR">Stuttgart</option>
</div>
```

Just open the snippet above on your iPhone and on your desktop. On your desktop you should see two elements, on your iPhone you will only see the correct version.

I think this is because specific elements are converted into iOS design components. In your case the system does not recognize your "select" as a valid element.